# Replacing tel or telprompt to call

Tags: ios, tel, telprompt

I've made an application is used to call predefined numbers upon button press. As far as i know the only way to make call inside app is to use "tel" or "telprompt". When i submitted an app i've received a rejection with this description:

> 2.5 Details
>
> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs, which is a
>   violation of the App Store Review Guidelines:
>
> teleprompt://
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted in the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

For my first submission I used "telprompt" to call, then I changed it to "tel" because i read here that many apps were accepted with it and after second submission i received the same response with rejection.
Can someone advice m how to use dial functions in app without "tel" or "telprompt"? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

upd: added text for second rejection

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your resubmission. We noticed that your app still uses
>   or references the teleprompt:// API, which is in violation of the App
>   Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We are unable to proceed with the review of your app until this issue
>   has been addressed.

Comment: Can you confirm that you received a rejection, exactly like the above, that referenced "tel:" as a non-public API? Note that it should be "tel:######" without any "//". The "tel:" scheme should be public.

Comment: Yes, i copied it. And in my app I used 'tel://' with '//'. I assume this may cause error?

Comment: `tel://` is not meaningful. "/" is not a legal digit.

Answer (score 3):

From your update, it suggests you're sending `tel://...` or `teleprompt://...` as a URL. The `tel:` scheme takes a series of digits. `/` is not a digit, so there's no reason you should be passing that as part of the number.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"+91 2308966";
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

This code is working for an app which I submitted to the Appstore.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the same I use. But for some reasons Apple rejects my app for the second time. That's how i use it:     

NSString *number = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:current.phone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:number]];

Comment: @dpaul93: use NSString *number = [@"tel:" stringByAppendingString:current.phone]
i.e. don't add the two slashes.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `telEprompt://` instead of `telprompt://`