# Copy/paste phone number into keypad or dial a toll free number in iOS programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, telephony, open-uri, telprompt

I am trying to make a call from my app using

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://1800000002"]];
```

> This is a toll free number in India.But while dialing, it is converting to +1(800)-000-000 (Converting and Saying dialing to United states number)

I have referred [Copy/paste phone number into keypad](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/copy-paste-phone-number-into-keypad-gone.1762716/) And [When I'm redialing a Toll free No. in India, iPhone is connecting USA](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4791641?start=0)]. But could not find the solution.

So can any please help me to avoid this ISD call Indian local call..

Comment: pls re phrase your question . Looks like copy/paste is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The telprompt wants the number in the international format. So you need to convert it to that. I *think* for India and the number you are trying to call, this should be `+911800000002`.

So this should work:

```
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://+911800000002"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
} else {
    // handle that case. e.g show number to user so that they can
    // type it in a phone manually or copy it to the clipboard and
    // notify user about that.
}
```

Depending on how the local numbers compared to international format works in India, you might need to remove the `1` on your number, not sure about that.

On a sidenote: You should always use the international format when dealing with phone numbers. Otherwise a device that is currently outside of the destination country may call somebody else or simply can't place the call at all.

Comment: With your answer ,My loop executes in "if" part in loop which again exhibits same issue

Comment: Did you try my comment with removing the 1? So use `+91800000002`? The problem you are having is not apple's API here, but that you need to know how the indian telephone numbering works according to international formats.

Comment: @ Michael Ochs, Yes I have tried this. but gave me message yes "This is not a valid number"..Only turn off the Dail assist only saved but that is manually function

Comment: @sujania can you dial the number like this in your iPhone manually?

Comment: For manual dialling , it is connecting to correct number without any format change

Comment: yes but you need to find the international number that works manually. (+91...). That's the number you need to put in there. I can't help you much with that as this is a local problem. In Germany our area codes all start with `0`, our international code is `+49` and when converting we skip the leading `0` of the area code. So e.g. local `0123456789` would be international `+49123456789`. Putting the latter in the `NSURL` works, no matter in which country the caller is in.

Comment: @sujania This might help as well: https://countrycode.org/india Seems like toll free numbers in international format need to start with `+91 080` in India.

Comment: @ Michael Ochs, thank you for the link , but the call is redirecting to wrong number without using 1 or invalid number with appending +91

Answer (score 1):

County code added (For India : +91)

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://+911800000002"]];
```

Generic way to find out country code

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];  // get the current locale.
NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode]; // get country code, e.g. ES (Spain), FR (France), etc.
```

Comment: thank you for post but Country code returns as "US" for me with your code which is supposed to  ISO country code is: in and the above telprompt again redirects me to ISD number

Comment: Hi @Sujania you might be checking on simulator, because I checked it & on device it returns correct value !

Comment: ,My requirement not to get the local country code , but to avoid calling toll free number as ISD when dial assist is on in user device phone settings. I am testing on iPhone5s Device only

Answer (score 0):

Your app might get rejected by Apple if you use telprompt. Use the following code to dial a number programmatically and see that you are inputting the number you'd like to call with correct format.

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"+1800000002;
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

source: [Replacing tel or telprompt to call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477108/replacing-tel-or-telprompt-to-call)

Comment: this is giving same me error as I m getting currently .

Comment: If you want to be sure to get the Indian number, why not append +91? So `@"+911800000002"`

Comment: @dirkgroten If i add +91 , than it is giving me massage as not a valid number

Comment: You app can be rejected if you doesn't check opening url so: if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL]) {..open url }

Comment: @Sujania, I think this has to do "Dial Assist" feature. Go to Settings -> Phone -> Switch off Dial Assist and see if it now works with `@"1800000002"` (don't put a "+"). Unfortunately there's no way to tell whether your users have this option on or off. I would file a bug with Apple about this not being recognised properly by Dial Assist.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you..Yes only with this it is giving a valid dail call..but trying  for same functionality when fail assist is enabled also...Hope as you said me, this may not be possible

Comment: This answer is incorrect. a) why should this get rejected? Using telprompt for years! b) specifying `+1` instead of `1...` makes the 1 the international code, which points to the USA.