# What is wrong in my function to make a call

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code to make a phone call

```
let phoneCall = phoneNumberTF.text
        if let phoneCall = phoneCall {
            let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneCall)")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)

        }else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "not correct phone", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
        }
```

I'm getting this error in the log

```
ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme tel
```

hint: I already check this question, but the solution didn't work with me
[Calling a phone number in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259824/calling-a-phone-number-in-swift)

Comment: Are you testing on a real device? You can't make calls in the simulator.

Comment: BTW - you should be checking the result of `openURL`.

Comment: @rmaddy oh really i can't even open the controller that makes the phone call?

Comment: The error message is coming from the call to `openURL`. That will fail on the simulator because there is no phone on the simulator.

Comment: Try changing `tel://` to `telprompt://`

Also it only works on an actual phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct url scheme is something like
`tel:PHONE_NUMBER` (without the slashes you included). you should also check if the application CAN open the url you provide by calling `UIApplication.sharedApplication.canOpenURL()`...

```
let phoneNumber = "123-456-789"
let phoneURL = NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)")!
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(phoneURL) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL)
}
```

Comment: sure: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Per Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

The correct format is `tel:`. So first change that and then you should check if the `UIApplication.sharedApplication.canOpenURL()` before doing it. If you're running on a simulator it will not work.

Comment: can i install the app for making the calls on the simulator ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli No you would need to run this on a real device.