# Button that makes a phone call in swift 2?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios9

I started coding a few weeks ago and I'm starting to make my first app, it's very simple.

I want the app to make a phone call once the user taps a certain button. I've been looking online and all the forums look outdated.

How am I supposed to program this feature into Xcode? Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29869513/4475605

Answer (score 7):

Telephone number link is treated as a URL with the `tel://` scheme:

```
@IBAction func makeCall(sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "tel://1234567890")!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! That was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Swift3:  
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)

Comment: Swift3 + handler: UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)