# open dialer on label click consisting of number

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I want to open dialer on click of label consisting of mobile number in swift 3 iOS.Please help me with this.

Comment: You Question is not clear can you give more information and show some code what you had try out

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259824/calling-a-phone-number-in-swift

Comment: Do we need to import cocoa in order to convert NSUrl to url because it is showing error cannot convert value NSURL to type URL in coercion. @ ami rt

Answer (score 1):

You can't make links clickable in a label unless you do it yourself with a gesture recognizer.

I suggest using a `UITextView` instead. You can turn off editing and make it look just like a label, then enable phone number detectors, set yourself up as the delegate of the text view, and dial the number when the user taps it. Take a look at the `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)` UITextViewDelegate method. You should be able to find example code showing how to do it.

### EDIT:

I have a project on Github called [DatesInSwift](https://github.com/DuncanMC/DatesInSwift) that uses clickable text fields as I've described, although it uses a custom URL scheme that links back to the app rather than dialing a phone number like you want. The idea is very similar, though, and you should be able to use the sample app as a guide.