# how can i add a call button to cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to develop my first app on IOS platform and i want  to add a call button to different cells and give each cell a different number to call because I want to programmatically add number to each cell to call ((for example I want cell A to call only the number 123 when I press the call button and I want the Cell B to only call 456 when I press the call button in that cell  , I have a service class where my data is stored and I have DeatilCell class to update my cell with different data  and another class to pass my data to the cells

I tried to search for some answers on the internet but I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

- [Have the specific phone number based on the index of the cell.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429652/detecting-uibutton-pressed-in-tableview-swift-best-practices)
- [Call it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259824/calling-a-phone-number-in-swift)

---

There are many approaches to get a value based on events inside `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` cells, just pick one.

Comment: this is better closed than re-answering