# How to trigger an emergency phone call

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create a button to trigger an emergency phone call on my app

The problem is that there's at least 3 main phone number ( 112, 911, 999)

Since you can do it natively on your phone is there a way to do it programmatically?

```
UIApplication.shared.open(number as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a phone number in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259824/calling-a-phone-number-in-swift)

Comment: @ZGski That's not a duplicate. The OP isn't asking how to call a phone number. The OP is asking how to know which emergency phone number to use.

Comment: I believe (but don't know 100%) that 112 will work globally; the carrier translates it to the local emergency number

Comment: It looks like it isn't 100%, but it will work in a lot of places https://www.triplezero.gov.au/Pages/Usingotheremergencynumbers.aspx#mob112

Comment: @ValentinScheldeman did you ever find an answer to this question? If so can you please post it

Comment: Hello @LanceSamaria sorry for the late answer i was sick and not working, I ended up just calling " 112 " as it is a number used pretty much everywhere, but i could found nothing from Apple to trigger the "emergency call" yourself like they can do :/

Comment: @ValentinScheldeman ok cool, thanks for getting back to me

Answer (score 2):

Check this page where you can find which number to call depending on where you are located. You can use JSON to extract the right data. https://favmaps.es/emergency/numbers/

Comment: Link-only questions are not recommended as it constitutes poor effort. In case if the link is dead, the answer will no longer be useful.