# Open phone app with auto populated number in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, external, openurl

Is there a way to open the phone app using swift? all the answer I see was to use `UIApplication.shared.open(urlNumber)` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260056/6800631). but it's not opening the phone app, instead, it will create a pop up and a `cancel` or `call` option.

This is my expected output
[image: expected output]

the code that I was using right now was

```
guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + "+639123123123") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(number, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

but like I said, it didn't open the phone app and the output of that code was this, which is not what I expect.

[image]

Android achieved it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699819), how about the ios?

Comment: i dont think so its possible ...

Comment: @jawadAli can you explain why? is there a link that says it cannot be done? so I can show it to my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to open direct phone app without dialogue. As Per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/) for openURL:

**openURL**

> When a third party application invokes openURL: on a tel://,
> facetime://, or facetime-audio:// URL, iOS displays a prompt and
> requires user confirmation before dialing.

Comment: For my expected result, it's okay to have a dialog before opening the phone app, as long as it opens the phone app, my current example code was a dialog but it didn't open the app, instead if you press call, it will automatically call that number.

Comment: its default behaviour ... there is no other API available to call

Comment: so it's not possible to open the phone app using swift?

Comment: I'm sorry but the link you provided doesn't say anything why I can't open the phone app, the answer was just saying that It's not possible to open the phone app and I still don't know why

Comment: so it did not helped you ? found anything that can work? or my answer is good enough ? :)

Comment: The answer was in your comment saying `its default behaviour ... there is no other API available to call`, I'm just get little bit confused but that does mean that there is no such a feature apple created. I pretty enlightened by the comments at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62580270/6800631 saying that `It can't be done by anyone unless Apple allows it`

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me, plus you don't have to add any additional action sheets or alerts. An action sheet automatically pops up.

```
@objc private func didTapCall() {
    let numberString = self.phoneText.text!
    guard let url = URL(string: "telprompt://\(numberString)") else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this achieves the desired outcome. I am surprised this is not the accepted answer (it should be!)