# Swift How do I get the dialer to open with phone number displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, phone-number

I don't need to call the phone number, I just need the dialer to open with the phone number already displayed. What `UIApplication.shared` should I open to achieve this?

My question was similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699819) one, but I don't seems to find any alternative for ios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
let phoneNumber = "+123123123"
let numberUrl = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(numberUrl) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(numberUrl)
}
```

Related links:

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open

Comment: It's not opening the dialer but instead show a dialog box and direct to call the number

Comment: Yes, it's ios native behaviour and you can't change that. iOS ask for the users consent to know if he wishes to call the number. You should know ios and android work differently.

Comment: Means I can't open the dialer in ios? if I'm right, can you give me the link to that explanation so I can explain it clearly in my client? because they want that function to appear in their app.

Comment: Yes, It can't be done by anyone unless Apple allows it, which is unlikely. Added related links.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the dialer/keypad within the phone app in iOS. Alternatively, you can design your own keypad in a view controller, add tones for keys and collect the number. Once you have the number, use following to make call:

```
func call() {

    let app = UIApplication.shared

    guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + "1234567890"), app.canOpenURL(number) else {
        return
    }
    app.openURL(number)
}
```

Comment: First: that app.openURL was already deprecated and changed to app.open, Second: It's not opening the dialer but instead show a dialog box and direct to call the number, which is not the answer I was looking for.