# How to auto dial a phone number using MAUI.Essentials?

Tags: maui

Without using Xam.Plugins.Messaging, how to auto dial a phone number using MAUI Essential package?

While using, PhoneDialer.Default.Open("12345"), its loading the default dialer in the device. Again the user need to press the Dial button. Any way to bypass this using Maui.Essentials package.?

Comment: Dial or Call? Dialing is when you enter the phone number, Calling is when you connect them.

Comment: No.  This would be an enormous security issue if apps were allowed to initiate calls without user interaction.

Comment: Hi @H.A.H., 

Yes we need the call the other party using the given no.

Comment: Hi @Jason, 
Using Android Studio, we can do this very easily. Don't know why its not possible in MAUI Apps.

Comment: If that's true, then whatever API you are using to do that should also be available in Xamarin.

Comment: @Jason, I dont know other solutions. I am still searching  for it. If you have any idea, pls let us know.

Comment: You just told me that this was “easy to do” in Android Studio.

Comment: @Jason, try like this.



Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+xxxxxxxx));//change the number  
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(callIntent);

Add CALL_PHONE  permission in the manifest file.

Comment: Pls refer this: 
https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android

Comment: @Jason I am not sure about newer versions. Older android version could do it without sweat. User interaction comes from giving permission to make calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if we use [Phone dialer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/phone-dialer?tabs=android), we could not dial a phone number directly.
For this, you can create a feature request here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose.

But as a workaround, you can use [Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code) to achieve this.

As a test, I added some test code to the official sample [NET MAUI - Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/platformintegration-invokeplatformcode/) and achieved this function on my side.

The steps are as follows:

1.create partial class `PhoneDialer.cs` in folder `Services.PartialMethods` and add a partial method `public partial void CallPhone(string number);` for it.

```
namespace InvokePlatformCodeDemos.Services.PartialMethods
{
    public partial class PhoneDialer
    {
        public partial void CallPhone(string number);
    }
}
```

2.achieve above partial method `CallPhone` in different platform.

I just achieved in Android platform, the code is:

```
 namespace InvokePlatformCodeDemos.Services.PartialMethods;

public partial class PhoneDialer
{
        public partial void CallPhone(string number) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
            callIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", number)); 
            callIntent.SetData(url);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(callIntent);

    }
}
```

3.In `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I add a Button to trigger this function:

```
using PartialMethodsPhoneDialer = InvokePlatformCodeDemos.Services.PartialMethods.PhoneDialer;

private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await RequestPhonePermission();
}

async Task RequestPhonePermission()
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Android)
        return;

    var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
    {
        status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Phone>();

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted) {
            var dialer = new PartialMethodsPhoneDialer();
            dialer.CallPhone("123");
            return;
        }

        if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.Phone>())
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permissions", "BECAUSE!!!", "OK");
        }

        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Phone>();

    }


    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Permission required",
            "Phone permission is required for calling. " +
            "We just want to do a test.", "OK");

    else if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted) {
        var dialer = new PartialMethodsPhoneDialer();
        dialer.CallPhone("123");
    }
}
```

Note:

1.Remember to add following persmission to `Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel"/>
  </intent>
</queries>
</manifest>
```

2.`Permission CALL_PHONE` belong to dangerous permission group.
So if your apps target SDK is 23 or higher and your device is running on Android 6.0 or higher, you must request for `CALL_PHONE` permission while the app is running. Also, we need to add `android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"` to `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

For this, you can check document: [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=android).

**Update:**

The file structure of the test app is as follows:

[image]

Comment: @Jessia Zhang,

Thank you for the reply. I tried. but facing some issues. From which name space we can import the Objects : Intent, Android etc to our Project ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it more clearly. We should achieved `PhoneDialer`  in Android platform,the folder is `Platforms->Android`. And the namespace I replaced `namespace 
 InvokePlatformCodeDemos.Platforms.Android` with `namespace InvokePlatformCodeDemos.Services.PartialMethods;` .

Comment: Then we can refer to the `PhoneDialer`  by  `using PartialMethodsPhoneDialer = InvokePlatformCodeDemos.Services.PartialMethods.PhoneDialer;` while we refer to it in `OurPage.xaml.cs`.

Comment: In fact, you can also refer to the official sample here: [InvokePlatformCodeDemos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/platformintegration-invokeplatformcode/),which is how it is implemented.

Comment: You mean to say the folders service and PartialMethods should be inside the platform folder ? then how we can refer the class in MainPage.xaml.cs ? I tried like this but method is not accusable. if you can share the project in Git, its helpful for me.

Comment: In face, the namespace for the implementation in folder `Platforms->Android` should be the same with the namespace of the partial class `PhoneDialer.cs ` we defined in folder `Services->PartialMethods`.  `public partial class PhoneDialer
    {
        public partial void CallPhone(string number);
    }`

Comment: I uploaded the file structure to my answer, you can check the updated part of the sample at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jessie Zhang. I did the same.... But showing this error. I missed something ?

Partial method 'PhoneDialer.CallPhone(string)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.

Comment: The same goes for my side of the code after it is built. If your other code is implemented correctly, you can just ignore this problem. I can deploy directly to my device.

Comment: Am getting this when I ignore and continue.     Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from ProcessRecord

Comment: Could you plz check this? I zipped the project and added in GIT.    >  https://github.com/riburajan/AutoDial.PhoneDialer.MAUI.git   .  Pls see what is happening....

Comment: Besides, I have added the runtime permission code to my answer, and updated the `AndroidManifest.xml`.  You can check it.

Comment: Hi  @Abhi,  sorry, I could not load your app correctly on my visual studio.  Could you please upload a correct one?

Comment: You can first try to add the permission code as I mentioned above. Please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Jessie, As per ur new changes, I modified the code and its working now.. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Congrats. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Definitely. I marked as Answered. One more thing,cant see any contact inform in your Profile.. pls send me via message. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll edit it later, if you have a new question, you can create a new thead and share it with me.

Comment: Sure.. Will do like that ... Really appreciate the helping hand.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy coding...  :)

Comment: Hi @Jessie, if need to do the same for iOS platform, what is the procedure?

Comment: I need to write code for iOS too

Comment: Hi @Abhi, after confirming with my iOS colleagues, IOS cannot implement this function of directly auto dialing a phone number.

Comment: Hi, oh god, you mean to say, the dialer will open , but user should press the dial button right ???    what to do? Any alternate solution..? I saw something in this link. > 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259824/calling-a-phone-number-in-swift  > 
Is it possible to convert to C# code ?

Comment: Ok Jessie, will wait for your reply.

Comment: My iOS physical device still needs to be audited and will be tested tomorrow. Have you tested the following code: ` NSUrl url = new NSUrl(string.Format(@"telprompt://{0}", number));
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);`

Comment: I didnt try iOS, since am new to iOS. dont know how to start .... :(

Comment: It's okay. I'll test it out tomorrow and I'll give you feedback. :)

Comment: Hi @Jessie, Please have a look into this :> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399956/launcher-default-tryopenasync-not-working-in-maui-app

Comment: I've implemented a demo like this before. Please check the answer I posted on the thread you shared.